# Vuex store doesn't update the state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My app has a small feature that if a user click on a particular image, it should get removed by a list and moved into another in the Vuex store.

It is something really simple:

```
// Action
  async movePicture({ commit }, data) {
    try {
      const comment = await this.$axios.$post('/photo-check', data)
      commit('MOVE_PHOTO', photoId)
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.response
    }
  },

  // Mutation
  MOVE_PHOTO: (state, id) => {
    const i = _.findIndex(state.list, p => p.id === id)
    if (i > -1) {
      const photo = state.list[i]
      state.list.splice(i, 1)
      state.visited.push(photo)
    }
  },
```

The point is that unfortunately this picture wont splice from the `list` and I do not understand why... Maybe I should use something specific to update arrays in Vuex and I don't know it... also I can not find any different solution than this...

Comment: Is vuex not updated or is your view representing the data not updated? I use the same construction and works perfectly. And you're sure the item is found in the state.list.

Comment: From where the `photoId` variable within the `movePicture` action come from? Have you checked if the index is the correct one before `splice`?

Comment: Can you confirm if the photo is being added properly to`state.visited` ?

Comment: The data is correctly passed, the id comes from the photo itself. Everything is correct by my point of view. If I add 2 `console.log` to display `list` and `visited` I still see the items not updating from the state. The index is always > than -1.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn’t good at handling these sitautions.

You should use

```
this.$delete(state.list, index)
```

[Vue.delete](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) does the magic bit for you.

Comment: Vue supports splice, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods, you shouldn't have to use the delete method

Comment: @dreijntjens Vue does, Vuex does not.

Comment: `Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the state, Vue components observing the state will update automatically. This also means Vuex mutations are subject to the same reactivity caveats when working with plain Vue`

As vuex is made reactive using vue it makes sence that vuex also supports splice? Wondering where you found it is not supperted

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats Vuex works the same way.